# compare tar content with local folder

Tags: tar, diff

I want to compare the content of a tar archive (backup of `$HOME`) with the content of my local `$HOME` to see whether there are files in the tar file which are not yet in the local filesystem.

What is the best way to do that?

I tried `tar -dvf archive.tar *` in `$HOME` already but the output is not really satisfying. It says `tar: Videos: Not found in archive` for some files and folders on the first directory level although they are in the archive and then it exits with `tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors` (exit code 2).

EDIT: It's on Ubuntu 10.04 and I'm quite familiar with the bash.

Comment: The problem is you're not using -f so tar isn't using your tar file as input as you're expecting.

Comment: Sorry, i just forgot the options here. I used them. EDITED

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

`tar -dvf example.tar`

(in the directory with which you're comparing)

The -d is the same as --diff / --compare

More info: http://www.apl.jhu.edu/Misc/Unix-info/tar/tar_16.html and http://ss64.com/bash/tar.html