# How can I check if a directory contains the same files of a TAR archive?

Tags: linux, filesystems, command-line-interface, tar, diff

Let's say I have a folder `Documents` and a TAR file `Documents.tar`, how to check if the tar file contains the same files that are present in the directory?

The more obvious solution to me would be to do:

```
$ tar xvf Documents.tar -C untarDocs
$ diff -r Documents untarDocs
```

Unfortunately this is very slow for large TAR files, is there any other alternative?

*Update: `tar -dvf Documents.tar` (or --diff, --compare) doesn't work because it doesn't detect a file that is present in the filesystem but not in the TAR file, it just detects a file present in the TAR file but not in the filesystem e.g.:

```
$ mkdir new
$ touch new/foo{1..4}
$ tar cvf new.tar new/
$ touch new/bar
$ tar --diff --verbose --file=new.tar       #### doesn't detect new/bar #########
$ rm new/foo1
$ tar --diff --verbose --file=new.tar
```

Output

```
new/
new/foo2
new/foo3
new/foo4
new/foo1
tar: new/foo1: Warning: Cannot stat: No such file or directory   ### works ###
```

Comment: Maybe `tar dvf Documents.tar`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [compare tar content with local folder](http://serverfault.com/questions/172385/compare-tar-content-with-local-folder)

Comment: @kasperd I've updated the answer with your solution, it doesn't work when a file present in the TAR file is missing in the directory.

Comment: @bangal I've updated the question, it is not a duplicate as the accepted answer of the other question doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that you tarred `/etc` directory and now you want to compare the tar filelist against the live filesystem. You can use the following commands to generate the filelist, and then `diff` the two list.

To generate the live filesystem list:

`find /etc | cut -c 2- | sort > fs.list`

To list the files inside tar:

`tar -tf etc.tar.gz | sed 's//$//' | sort > tar.list`

Finally, compare the two lists with:

`diff fs.list tar.list`

Please note that `cut` and `sed` machinery is only here to deal with starting/ending slashes. Maybe you can use more concise methods to strip the offending slashes, but the example above should work.